# Converting an Integral to a Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, riemann-sum

I have an integral over $t$ where I choose $t$ takes discrete values $t=0,1,2,...$ and would like to write the integral as a sum using the same function.  I realize that this is not necessarily possible unless one is using a counting measure or something like that.

In the case of a one-dimensional Riemann sum over an interval from analysis, one can write

$\int^b_af(x) dx =\lim_{||\Delta x \rightarrow 0||} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x^*_i) \Delta x_i.$

Are there are other ways the integral can be changed to a sum? (I mean an actual equality and not an approximation with a remainder error term, although it could be something where the error term vanishes in the limit).

Comment: Note that the formula you've written is incorrect over some pernicious examples. For example, if $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\mathbb Q\\0&x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$then the integral evaluates to $0$ under the Lesbegue definition of the integral, but the sum limit will evaluate the integral to be $b-a$.

Comment: I thought that was an example of something which was Lebesgue integrable, but not Riemann integrable.  Is what I have written basically the definition of the 'Riemann integral'?

Comment: Well, you are correct that the Riemann integral cannot be evaluated over this $f$, but note that your sum can, and produces a weird answer.

Comment: Hmm OK, I'll think about this.  Is there basically no completely consistent way of writing an integral out as a sum, even if a counting measure is used?